# Using LINQ left join with multiple conditions and subquery

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to left join two tables and sum one field so I made this query:

```
IQueryable<Reference.Inventory.SearchDetailRequester> _qRequester =
    from a in dbErp.EPROC_TR_ER_DETAIL
    join b in dbErp.EPROC_TR_INVENTORY on
    new Reference.Inventory.SearchDetailRequester { ID_REQUEST = a.ID_REQUEST , ID_KATALOG = a.ID_KATALOG}
    equals
    new Reference.Inventory.SearchDetailRequester { ID_REQUEST = b.ID_REQUEST, ID_KATALOG = b.ID_KATALOG }
    into inv_join 
    from c in inv_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where a.ID_REQUEST == ID_REQUEST && a.APROVE_BY_DS == 1 && a.APROVE_BY_GS == 1

    select new Reference.Inventory.SearchDetailRequester
    {
        ID_KATALOG = a.ID_KATALOG,
        TYPE_OF_GGS = a.TYPE_OF_GGS,
        TRANSACTION_TYPE = "OUT",
        DATE = c.DATE ?? "",
        QTY = -1 * c.QTY ?? a.QTY,
        ID_INVENTORY = c.ID_INVENTORY,
        QTY_AVAILABLE = ((from d in dbErp.EPROC_TR_INVENTORY
                          where d.ID_KATALOG == a.ID_KATALOG
                          group d by new { d.ID_KATALOG } into e
                          select new { qty_ava = (System.Int32)e.Sum(p => p.QTY ?? 0) }).FirstOrDefault().qty_ava)
    };
```

but when I debug I got this message :

> The type 'Reference.Inventory.SearchDetailRequester' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to to the join with anonymous type, I don't think you can choose a class like you did:

```
new { ID_REQUEST = a.ID_REQUEST , ID_KATALOG = a.ID_KATALOG}
equals
new { ID_REQUEST = b.ID_REQUEST, ID_KATALOG = b.ID_KATALOG }
```

If for example `b.ID_KATALOG` is nullable in the database, you can solve it like this:

```
new { ID_REQUEST = a.ID_REQUEST , ID_KATALOG = a.ID_KATALOG}
equals
new { ID_REQUEST = b.ID_REQUEST, ID_KATALOG = (int)b.ID_KATALOG }
```

That is assuming ID_KATALOG is an `int` of course.
Or you can do it the other way around too normally:

```
new { ID_REQUEST = a.ID_REQUEST , ID_KATALOG = (int?)a.ID_KATALOG}
equals
new { ID_REQUEST = b.ID_REQUEST, ID_KATALOG = b.ID_KATALOG }
```

Comment: it's not working .net read error with this message: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: still not work with this messge: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

Comment: Is one of the properties in the anonymous type nullable for b but not for a? (int? ID_Request for a != int ID_Request for b, even if they are the same in db)

Comment: yes,  QTY_AVAILABLE default is null so I made query with left join and subquery to get the sum

Comment: No not in the select, in the anonymous type (the `new { ID_REQUEST = a.ID_REQUEST , ID_KATALOG = a.ID_KATALOG}...`

Comment: in a side there are some ID_KATALOG with null value. Is that the problem?

Comment: I try to delete null record in "a" side, but it's still got same error message

Comment: The problem isn't that a record is null, the problem is that it COULD be null so it throws errors, that's why you need a cast

Comment: it's still not work, .net give same error message. Is there any option to change my query with same result?

Comment: @Karl The initial answer is correct according to the problem described in your post and should be accepted. The further problems are unrelated, so either resolve them yourself, or post another question and provide your entity classes, so the people trying to help not guessing the information needed.

Comment: He means you can accept the answer (shameless rep hunting), you can do that by clicking the green arrow next to my answer :)

Comment: Sorry i'm still newbie here :p